# Cleanest way to map 2 Keys to the same value in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, functional-programming, mapping

I have a map where there are two kinds of strings that have to map to the same value. For example, the key either has to be exactly "Test 1" or exactly "Test 1 Extra" and they are both mapped to the value `1`

```
val result = Map(
    "Test 1" -> 1,
    "Test 1 Extra" -> 1,
    "Test 2" -> 2,
    "Test 2 Extra" -> 2,
    "Test 3" -> 3,
    "Test 3 Extra" -> 3
)
```

With the above, it's a bit unwieldy especially if there were more similar key value pairs. I can imagine there's an easier way to do this, possibly with Regular Expressions to take into account the string `Extra` that may be in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an inspiration:

```
case class DoubleKey[X](x1: X, x2: X) {
  def ->[A](a: A): List[(X, A)] = List(x1, x2).map((_, a))
}

def twice(extra: String)(s: String) = DoubleKey(s, s + extra)

val withExtra = twice(" extra") _
val res = List(
  withExtra("Test 1") -> 1, 
  withExtra("Test 2") -> 2, 
  withExtra("Test 3") -> 3
).flatten.toMap

println(res)
```

No regular expressions needed.